# Laravel 5.1 Complicated Relationship Query Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.1

Relationship: Receipt hasMany LineItems

```
$columns = ['rece_id','rece_user_id','rece_name','rece_date']

$builder = Receipt::select($columns)
        ->with('lineItems')
        ->where('rece_user_id', Auth::user()->id)

dd($builder->get()->toArray());
```

Above code gives me the receipts with their all respective related line items (all columns).

I need only first line item's one column e.g. liit_description. (I need that as another column in `$columns` list).

Is this even possible with Eloquent?

**UPDATE**

I solved it by Using DB query instead of Eloquent (But I prefer a Eloquent solution, if someone can help)

```
        $builder = DB::table('receipts')->select($columns)
        ->join('line_items', function ($join) {
            $join->on('receipts.rece_id', '=', 'line_items.liit_rece_id');
        })
        ->where('rece_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
        ;
```

If this can be converted into Eloquent query, it would be fun.

Comment: why not to use ->first() instead of get()

Comment: @ClearBoth I need all the receipts but only with **first** lineitem.

Answer (score 0):

```
$builder = Receipt::with(['lineItems' => function ($query) {
        $query->first('liit_description');
    }])->where('rece_user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)->get($columns);
```

Comment: Ok that gives me the entire first line item. I need to select only one column from line_item in this query.

Comment: `value()` function is returning null array

Comment: maybe means that column is null? you can try  pluck() instead. Otherwise specify the inner query as you like by adding ->select($columns) and you can chain method as you like

Comment: tried select in the inner query but it didn't get me the result

Comment: try has(column_name) method

Comment: I tried has() list() pluck(), `$query->first()->has('liit_description');` but nothing worked. [See my update in question, I made it work using DB query, can you help convert that to Eloquent].

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118676/discussion-between-clearboth-and-karmendra).

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by Using Join with Eloquent, surprisingly it worked (Nothing about join in Eloquent Doc)

Added `liit_description` in $columns array, And

```
$builder = Receipt::select($columns)
    ->join('line_items', function ($join) {
        $join->on('receipts.rece_id', '=', 'line_items.liit_rece_id');
    })
    ->where('rece_user_id', Auth::user()->id)
;
```